# Update Charts when Pivot Filter Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have two charts on one Excel sheet with a slicer that connect to pivot tables on another sheet. The code I have will change the axis of the charts if I run the code independently, so working correctly. However, I'm trying to get the code to run when the slicer selection changes and I cannot find anything that will run.

This is one piece of code that I've tried to call the macro, but I keep receiving the below error.  Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined. I'm copying and pasting the sub's name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)


    If Target.Name = "Pivot Table1" Then
        
        Call AdjustVerticalAxis
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `AdjustVerticalAxis()`? in a worksheet module or a standalone module? Do you define the sub as `Private Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()`?

Comment: AdjustedVertiaclAxis() is in a standalone module in the workbook labeled ThisWorkbook. The sub isn't defined as Private Sub AdjustVerticalAxis(). I tested it as a Private Sub and it didn't solve the issue immediately.

Comment: Define sub as `Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()` or `Public Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()`, revise your code as `Call ThisWorkbook.AdjustVerticalAxis`.  _**OR**_   move the code `Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()` to a standdard module (insert > module  ), then `Call AdjustVerticalAxis` works well. `https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Ktw.gif`

Comment: I moved the Sub to a module and that resolved the issue. Thank you!!!!